# Beautifulsoup not returning child elements

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I've tried this a million different ways and can't figure out why Beautifulsoup is as unpredictable as all my exes.

I'm just trying to copy a table to a pandas dataframe. There's about 280 rows in the table.

Here's the url:

```
https://www.brilliantearth.com/design-your-own-engagement-ring/?sid=3755106&dc=
```

Here's part of my code that doesn't work:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "https://www.brilliantearth.com/design-your-own-engagement-ring/?sid=3755106&dc="
    r = s.get(url, headers=req_headers)

#add contents of urls to soup variable from each url
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
rows = soup.find_all("div", {"id": "diamonds_search_table"})
rows
```

Here's the are within the url where the table is:

[image]

What can I try next?

Comment: Could you please post a pic of the inspected div?

Comment: In what way does your code not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript. You can use `requests` module to simulate it.

For example:

```
import json
import requests


search_parameters = {
'shapes':  "Round",
'cuts':    "Fair,Good,Very Good,Ideal,Super Ideal",
'colors':  "J,I,H,G,F,E,D",
'clarities':   "SI2,SI1,VS2,VS1,VVS2,VVS1,IF,FL",
'polishes':    "Good,Very Good,Excellent",
'symmetries':  "Good,Very Good,Excellent",
'fluorescences':   "Very Strong,Strong,Medium,Faint,None",
'min_carat':   "0.25",
'max_carat':  "11.58",
'min_table':   "50.00",
'max_table':   "86.00",
'min_depth':   "46.20",
'max_depth':   "629.00",
'min_price':   "420",
'max_price':   "1258930",
'stock_number':    "",
'row': "0",
'page':    "1",
'requestedDataSize':   "200",
'order_by':    "price",
'order_method':    "asc",
'currency':    "$",
'has_v360_video':  "",
'dedicated':   "",
'sid': "",
'min_ratio':   "1.00",
'max_ratio':   "2.75",
'shipping_day':    "",
'MIN_PRICE':   "420",
'MAX_PRICE':   "1258930",
'MIN_CARAT':   "0.25",
'MAX_CARAT':  "11.58",
'MIN_TABLE':   "45",
'MAX_TABLE':   "86",
'MIN_DEPTH':   "46.2",
'MAX_DEPTH':   "629"
}

data = requests.get('https://www.brilliantearth.com/loose-diamonds/list/', params=search_parameters).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for d in data['diamonds']:
    print('{:<30} {:<15} {}'.format(d['title'], d['cut'], d['price']))
```

Prints:

```
0.30 Carat Round Diamond       Very Good       420
0.30 Carat Round Diamond       Very Good       420
0.30 Carat Round Diamond       Ideal           430
0.30 Carat Round Diamond       Ideal           430
0.30 Carat Round Diamond       Good            430
0.30 Carat Round Diamond       Ideal           430
0.30 Carat Round Diamond       Very Good       430
0.25 Carat Round Diamond       Super Ideal     430
0.30 Carat Round Diamond       Very Good       430
0.32 Carat Round Diamond       Ideal           430

... and so on.
```

Comment: Man, this is awesome. Where did you get that url from though? It's returning some data, but not the data from the original url/query

Comment: @max I found the URL in Firefox developer tools - the page loads the data from this URL. (Chrome has something similar)

Comment: Got it. that's where I thought it came from. I haven't found it yet - still digging around to figure out how to get the right data in that search-diamonds/list/ url.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `selenium` for parsing `html`.You can try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.brilliantearth.com/design-your-own-engagement-ring/?sid=3755106&dc=')

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)


rows = soup.find_all("div", {"id": "diamonds_search_table"})
print(rows)
```

You will get all rows like below:

```
[<div class="search-table" id="diamonds_search_table" style="position: relative; height: 34000px;">
<div class="inner item" data-have="true" data-position="0" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 34px;top:0px;"><a class="td-n2" href="/rings/cyorings/view_diamond/9361809/?sid=3755106&amp;first=diamond&amp;show_diamond_tab=true"></a><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table-striped table-hover search-result-table" width="100%"><tbody><tr class="search-item"><td data-id="9361809" onclick="dtl.stop_jump();" scope="col" width="7%"><div class="checkbox checkbox-ty4"><label><input class="hidden"/><span class="sr-only">checkbox</span><i class="icons-checkbox"></i></label></div></td><td scope="col" width="9%">Round</td><td scope="col" width="9%">0.30</td><td scope="col" width="8%">H</td><td scope="col" width="8%">SI2</td><td scope="col" width="12%">Very Good</td><td scope="col" width="8%">GIA</td><td scope="col" width="12%">Botswana Sort</td><td class="width_ratio_hide" scope="col" width="8%">1</td><td scope="col" width="10%">$420</td><td scope="col" width="7%"><span class="view">View</span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="inner item" data-have="true" data-position="34" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 34px;top:34px;"><a class="td-n2" href="/rings/cyorings/view_diamond/9391074/?sid=3755106&amp;first=diamond&amp;show_diamond_tab=true"></a><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table-striped table-hover search-result-table" width="100%"><tbody><tr class="search-item"><td data-id="9391074"


and so on...........]
```